# MongoDB aggregation: Count documents in a query for each array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here's an example through JS code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
let waiting = findSessions()  // regular query for status "WAITING"
let results = [];
for (let w of waiting) {

  // Only push it to results if the w.members[0] and TARGET_USER_ID have never matched before.
  // Meaning, in the "session" collection, there are no documents that have these 2 IDs in the members field
  if (!hasMatchedBefore(w.members[0], "TARGET_USER_ID")) {
    results.push(w);
  }
}
```

***IGNORE MOST OF WHAT'S ABOVE***

Just realized how poorly written the old question was. Let's start from the beginning.

Consider the collection "sessions":

```
[
    {
      status: "WAITING",
      type: "TEXT",
      members: [
        "adam"
      ]
    },
    {
      status: "WAITING",
      type: "TEXT",
      members: [
        "john"
      ]
    },
    {
      status: "WAITING",
      type: "VOICE",
      members: [
        "alex"
      ]
    },
    {
      status: "ENDED",
      type: "VOICE",
      members: [
        "adam",
        "alex"
      ]
    },
    {
      status: "TIMEOUT",
      type: "TEXT",
      members: [
        "adam",
        "TARGET"
      ]
    }
]
```

I'm making a match-matching system. Let's say "TARGET" wants to match. I'm trying to write a MongoDB aggregation that does the following.

1. Find all documents with query { type: "TEXT", status: "WAITING" }
2. Iterate through each document: check if `members[0]` and `TARGET` have ever matched before
3. If `members[0]` and `TARGET` have matched before (check entire collection, any type/status), then it will not be included in the final array

It should return the following:

```
[
    {
      status: "WAITING",
      type: "TEXT",
      members: [
        "john"
      ]
    },
]
```

Notice how there were 3 "WAITING" rooms in the collection. But `TARGET` had already matched with `adam`. And `TARGET` cannot match with `alex`, because `alex` is in a "VOICE" session. So in this case, `john` would be the only appropriate match.

Comment: Please provide your requested result for the sample documents. What is `"TARGET_USER_ID"` in this case?

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know does it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$lookup` on the same collection:

```
db.sessions.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      status: "WAITING",
      type: "TEXT",
      "members.0": {$ne: target}
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "sessions",
      let: {member: {$first: "$members"}},
      pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$setIsSubset: [["$$member", target], "$members"]}}}],
      as: "found"
  }},
  {$match: {"found.0": {$exists: false}}},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      members: {$push: {$arrayElemAt: ["$members", 0]}},
      status: {$first: "$status"},
      type: {$first: "$type"}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aFOdJo9xbNb)

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately. If I changed "ID2" to "ID9", then it should have returned all of the waiting rooms, but instead, it returns no response.

Comment: I've edited my question a second time. This time it should be much more clear as to what I'm trying to achieve. @nimrodserok

Comment: This is perfect, removed the last stage however. I got stuck when I realized I couldn't use use $all within the $lookup $match pipeline, did not know $setIsSubset was a thing! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have a solution for you.

**Data**

```
  [
  {
    _id: "ObjectId1",
    status: "WAITING",
    "members": [
      "ID1"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "ObjectId2",
    status: "WAITING",
    "members": [
      "ID2"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "ObjectId3",
    status: "ENDED",
    "members": [
      "ID1",
      "ID2"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Query**

```
    db.collection.find({
  status: "ENDED",
  members: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $eq: "ID2"
    }
  }
})
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId3",
    "members": [
      "ID1",
      "ID2"
    ],
    "status": "ENDED"
  }
]
```

**Note:** Please check mongoplayground link. 
Main Solution: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xkyyW8gsWV6  
Other Solution: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1ndltdDU38-